# String comparison from a list in for loop

Tags: java, loops

I'm trying to compare strings from a list in a for loop but I can't really find the syntax for it. I want to change the iterator (in this case `i`) to not be the index, instead, I want it it to be the value.

```java
list.add(lrow);
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    if (lrow.equals(i)){
    }
}
handler.getGalagaState().entityManager.entities.add(new EnemyBee(0 , 0, 32 , 32, handler, row, column));
```

Comment: [`list.get(i)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#get(int))

Answer (score 3):

You have to get value from `ArrayList` by index. You can do it like this:

```
list.get(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to change the iterator (in this case i) to not be the index, instead, I want it it to be the value.

'i' is not the iterator. Its just a variable of type integer that let's you setup a condition for iterating through a Collection.

With that being said, how would you implement the condition-check for continuing or exiting the loop when the control-variable is of type String?

Your comparison should look like this:

`if (lrow.equals(list.get(i)))`

`list.get(i)` gets you the element at index i in your List.